# save the value created in the method c#

Tags: c#

The Create() method runs 3 times at the same time. OpidNum starts empty the first time they run. It takes a number and saves it to the variable.

What I want to do is when the Create() method runs again, I want it to use the previously retrieved number.

If I define a global variable they can get the same number. I don't want this to happen. Defining a collection might work but my brain has stopped.

My current code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Work();
    }

    private static async void Work()
    {
        while (true)
        {

                Create();
                await OtherMethod();
        }
    }

    private static void Create()
    {
        
    }
```

Comment: "If I define a global variable they can get the same number" - so do something to ensure thread safety, like [using a lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock) for example :)

Comment: It slows down the program speed. It must be asynchronous. @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: You cannot share between threads without synchronizing access to the shared data.

Comment: @mahvettin it does indeed. You can also change your `Create()` method to accept the ID as a parameter - then you can prepare the ID values ahead of time and `Parallel.ForEach` over that.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to reuse some computation, you should probably consider [`Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=net-7.0), this is optionally thread safe.

Your provided example is really unclear what it intends to do, since it does not actually produce any value. So an arbitrary example of Lazy could look something like this:

```
public class MyClass{
    private Lazy<string> myLazy;
    public MyClass(){
        myLazy = new Lazy<string>(MyMethod, true);
    }
    private string MyMethod(){
        // do expensive computation
    }
    public string GetValue() => myLazy.Value;
}
```

If all your code is static you could make a static field, but mutable global fields can be problematic. So I would probably prefer creating a class and an instance of this class if possible.